# mySql query gives me wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, query-string

I have the following table named **question**:

```
  `questionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `questioncategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questionstatusID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `organizationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `legalformID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionProtocolID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionDisplayedRecordID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questionTitle` text NOT NULL,
  `questionSummary` text,
  `questionText` longtext NOT NULL,
  `questionAnswerSummary` text,
  `questionAnswerText` longtext,
  `questionMetaTags` text,
  `questionAskedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questionAnsweredBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionAskedOnDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `questionAnsweredOnDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionAskedFromIp` varchar(255) NOT NULL
```

I am trying to build conditional query, that is user have option in my search form to search for:

category (questioncategoryID) 
legal form (legalformID)
From Date (questionAnsweredOnDate)
To Date (questionAnsweredOnDate)
Search Term

**User may leave all fields blank, or it can use all of them.**

More explanations:

1. Category (questioncategoryID) - if it leave it blank it means he want to see questions from all categories, if not he want to see only the questions from specific category.
2. Legal form (legalformID) - if it leave it blank it means he want to see questions with all legal forms, otherwise he want to see only the questions that has specific legalformID
3. From Date (questionAnsweredOnDate) only questions that are answered after this date (he is allowed to leave this field blank)
4. To Date (questionAnsweredOnDate) only questions that are answered until this date (he is allowed to leave this field blank)
5. Search Term if it is not blank search term should be found in: questionTitle OR in questionSummary OR in questionText (he is allowed to leave this field blank)

I am trying to get the data with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`question`) 
    WHERE `questioncategoryID` = 5
    AND `legalformID` = 16 
    AND `questionTitle` LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%' 
    OR `questionSummary` LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%' 
    OR `questionText` LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%' 
    OR `questionMetaTags` LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%' 
    ORDER BY `questionAskedOnDate` DESC
```

but this query returns me questions that belongs to categories 5,10 and 7 and also questions that have legalformID 0,3 and 16....

As you can see I didn't try even to use the dates, since I can't make the query to work correctly even without them. So please, include the dates in your solution.

Comment: Put parentheses around your conditions in the `where`.  This is always desirable when you are mixing `AND` and `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you intend:

```
WHERE `questioncategoryID` = 5 AND
      `legalformID` = 16 AND
      (`questionTitle` LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%' OR
       `questionSummary` LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%' OR
       `questionText` LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%' OR
       `questionMetaTags` LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%' 
      )
```

Use parentheses in the `WHERE` when you mix `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: If I change my query in categoryID = 6 and legalformID = 16, query returns 0 results, and I have one question in the database that have categoryID = 6, legalformID = 16 and Lorem Ipsum in title

Comment: sorry my mistake...i was looking in wrong cell, after an hour staring in the code...I mix the fields...thanks for the help

Comment: @user2417624 . . . You would add `AND` followed by some condition on the dates.

Comment: In which part of the query the AND should come? After the legalformID?

Comment: It can actually go anywhere but `legalformID = 16 AND <date condition> AND` would work fine.

Comment: Thanks...I will check that first thing in the morning....hopefully it will work fine